# How OpenStreetMap data layer works

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, vector, features

OpenStreetMap (OSM) map has a data layer and an information panel.

How is it implemented?

What is a type of the layer and URL of vector data source?

How information panel works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example call to the OSM API generated by the data layer: http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=-122.29555,37.814276,-122.291602,37.81692

Be aware that the API server will aggressively throttle you if you make excessive requests - it's there for the editors. If you're interested in making bulk queries, a good strategy is to mirror the data yourself, for which *excellent* support exists in the hourly and minute replication diffs.

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented as a query to the OpenStreetMap API, for the given region.
It's also not something you want to copy, as it scales poorly, and many regions are now mapped too densely for the results to work properly.